# Comparing classifiers for multi-label classification predictions

Tags: r, correlation, statistical-significance, categorical-data, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I have a multi-label classification problem (categorical predicted values: A, B, C, D) and I want to test the null hypothesis that there is no significant difference between the classifiers, and the difference in the accuracy is by chance.
Let's assume the actual outcome, the output of classifierA and the output of classifierB are as following:

> actual_outcome <- sample(LETTERS[1:4], 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.1, 0.2, 0.65, 0.05)) %>% as.data.frame()

> classifierA <- sample(LETTERS[1:4], 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.1, 0.2, 0.65, 0.05)) %>%  as.data.frame()

> classifierB <- sample(LETTERS[1:4], 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.1, 0.2, 0.65, 0.05)) %>% as.data.frame()

Is it possible to do a Rank Correlation test (rcorr.cens) from Hmisc package in R with categorical variables? The other option is to use Wilcoxon Signed Rank test, but the problem with this test is that it doesn't take the actual values (or the deterministic correct responses) into account.

Comment: I do not think rank correlation is likely to be the answer here but your question is not quite clear to me. I think it might help to edit your question to define what you mean by more concordant.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I edited the question.

Comment: Is your goal to test multiple proportions, kind of an ANOVA for proportions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are purely interested in the differential accuracy of two classifiers which i shall call P and Q since your categories are already A, B, C, D then consider this.

Any case where P and Q give the same output is uninformative for their differential accuracy although obviously it is relevant for their accuracy in absolute terms. So they can be removed. The you can remove any observation where neither P nor Q gave the correct prediction even if they gave different ones as that too is not informative for their differential accuracy. You now have only two sorts of observation left, ones where P is right and Q wrong and ones where Q is right and P is wrong. Under the null they should be equi-probable and you can test for that with a binomial test.

Of course if A, B, C and D are in fact ordered then that does not work but in that case you have other problems altogether.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Nope, they are not ordered. I will exclude the uninformative categories and will do a binomial test of significance.